# ssl error invalid or self-signed certificate magento

Tags: image, ssl

I have installed magento on my local server (wamp). Everything is going good, but when i am uploading an image for a product . I get an error "ssl error invalid or self-signed certificate".

What should i do? I am very very frustrated with it.

Comment: Check this solution: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/76146/1916

Answer (score 6):

The Flash Upload doesn't handle invalid or self-signed certificates. It just throws an error, therefore you have two possibilites:

1. Create a certificate and make sure it is trusted in your system (don't ask me how!)
2. Just remove the https from the url and use http on your local dev system (the url can be changed in the backend: `System > Config > Web > (Un)secure Baseurl`

Comment: _Create a certificate and make sure it is trusted in your system_ Using OpenSSL, you must create a Certification Authority and then create a server certificate/key pair, sign the server key with the CA Certificate and then import the CA certificate into Internet Explorer's Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate Store (which makes it available to Chrome and to the Flash Flex file uploader) and Firefox's Certificate Manager Authorities Store, you'll have a lot better luck running your test web server with SSL self-signed Certs.

Comment: Fiasco, you are invited to either give your own answer or just edit my post :-)

Comment: As soon as I dig up the steps... describing it is kind of incomplete. Trying to find the notes.

Comment: I have the same problem. And the problem have nothing to do with SSL at all. It is dev environment without https.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using ssl on your dev environment to prevent unforeseen issues when moving to staging/production.

If you have a self-signed certificate, and have issue uploading product in admin you can add self-signed certificate to your root certificate

**For Mac Os** See [Resolving SSL Self-Signed Certificate Errors](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/SOURCETREEKB/Resolving+SSL+Self-Signed+Certificate+Errors) Using Safari will fix the issue in other browsers.

Open Safari and enter he url in the address bar then follow the instruction below and then restart your browser

[image]

**For Windows** see [Installing a Self-Signed Certificate as a Trusted Root CA in Windows Vista](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2007/04/10/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista.aspx) Using IE will fix the issue in other browsers.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. And the problem have nothing to do with SSL at all. It is dev environment without https.

Answer (score 0):

64bit Firefox can also cause this problem, switching to 32bit Firefox solved this and other permission problems for me.